# Why is my public IP address the same as my private IP address?

Tags: networking, network-programming, ip-address

It should be impossible right? But I used ipconfig and it is exactly the same as when I use a website to check my public IP address. They both start with 76.

Comment: Because you're on a broadband network? or not behind a router? Not impossible at all. Off topic.

Comment: My university's computer science department had a public IP address for every individual computer because, being a computer science department at a well-established university, they got there first when plenty of IP addresses were available. Very cool! Of course, there was also a firewall in front of the network.

Answer (score 1):

**It is possible to have public IP the same as your private one of course.**

It seems like you are plugged directly into your ISP's network, without any NAT or other router in your way.